# Pop-Up Info Window on Mouse Over

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to implement a pop-up window on mouse over to display a basic thumbnail displaying all the info about said entry.

Below is my index view:

[image: Index View]

Below is the thumbnail window I would like to display when the mouse hovers over any of the Software Name's.

[image: Thumbnail]

Any help is appreciate, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming popup is the ID of your "description box":

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
This is the main container.
<div id="popup" style="display: none">some text here</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var e = document.getElementById('parent');
e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Alternatively you can get rid of JavaScript entirely and do it just with CSS:**

**CSS**

```
.parent .popup {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is iterate through all the `<tr> </tr>` with JQuery and append a html element in which you add your thumbnail. Something like:

```
 $('#table tr').each(function (i, obj) {
        $(obj).mouseenter(function () {
            $('body').append("<div id='hoveringTooltip' style='position:fixed;'></div>");
            $('#hoveringTooltip').html("your thumbnail");
            $('#hoveringTooltip').css({
                "top": (obj.getBoundingClientRect().top + 20),
                "left": obj.getBoundingClientRect().left,
                "background-color": "white",
                "border": "1px solid black"
            });
        });
        $(obj).mouseleave(function () {
            $('#hoveringTooltip').remove();
        });
    })
```

As you can see I apply some css to the div apended in order to show it near the mouse location.